# Excel 2013 - VBA - Object Required | Run-time Error '424'

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new to VBA and was trying to setup a macro that will send out an email from a button. I have the following code:

```
Sub SendHTMLEmail(what_address1 As String, subject_line1 As String, mail_body1 As String)

    Dim olapp As Outlook.Application
    Set olapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim olmail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set olmail = olapp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    olmail.To = what_address1
    olmail.Subject = subject_line1
    olmail.HTMLBody = mail_body1
    olmail.Display

End Sub

Sub SendHoldingEmail()

    row_number = 1

    Do
        DoEvents

        row_number = row_number + 1
        Dim mail_body_message As String
        Dim full_name As String
        Dim Email_Subject As String

        mail_body_message = EmailWording.Range("E4")
        Email_Subject = EmailWordings.Range("D4")
        Call SendHTMLEmail("", Email_Subject, mail_body_message)

    Loop Until row_number = 2

End Sub
```

I'm getting the error when I try and continue past this. Could you advise where I am going wrong?

I did search through and looked at the articles with this error but still couldn't get it to work. What am I missing?

Comment: You use both `EmailWording` and `EmailWordings` as worksheets - I suspect one is a typo.

Comment: in your code you don't have any `To` address to send

Comment: what line throws the error? what is `EmailWording`? and is this latter supposed to be the same as `EmailWordings`?

Comment: EmailWordings is a worksheet I've named on Excel. So in cells E4 and D4 there is text that will be put onto the email once it generates from clicking the button. Cell E4 has HTML that will go into the body of the email. The "To" field in the email has been left blank on purpose as the email address will change.

Comment: I'm not sure that you can set the `To` property to an empty string. What happens if you skip assigning the To property by removing/commenting-out that line?

Comment: Apart from the fact that you have to tell us where the error occurs, I'm presuming that you have already assigned `EmailWordings`? I cannot see any assignment to the worksheet. if you haven't, you will have to  assign it as: `Dim EmailWordings as Worksheet : Set EmailWordings = Worksheets("EmailWordings")`

Comment: @Zac if he has changed the Codename of the Sheet to EmailWordings, this is not necessary

Comment: @gizlmo did not know that. just tried and you are absolutely correct. learn something new every day :)

Comment: Annoyingly it isn't telling me where the error occurs. When I click the Continue button in VBA it doesn't highlight anything.

Comment: And yes, sorry, the sheet is called EmailWordings

Comment: try stepping through the Sub. you should then be able to pin point which line is throwing the error

Comment: @Adam try selecting Break In Class Module http://www.cpearson.com/excel/BreakInClassModule.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Set the reference to `Microsoft Outlook [version number] Object Library` in Tools/references in the IDE.

2) Make sheet references consistent. The following lines of code references two sheets, not just one:

```
mail_body_message = EmailWording.Range("E4")
Email_Subject = EmailWordings.Range("D4")
```

3) Finally do some code cleanup, use `Option Explicit` and proper code indentation.

This works for me:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SendHTMLEmail(what_address1 As String, subject_line1 As String, mail_body1 As String)

    Dim olapp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olmail As Outlook.MailItem

    Set olapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olmail = olapp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    olmail.To = what_address1
    olmail.Subject = subject_line1
    olmail.HTMLBody = mail_body1
    olmail.Display

End Sub

Sub SendHoldingEmail()

    Dim EmailWording As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim row_number As Long
    Dim Email_Subject As String, full_name As String, mail_body_message As String

    Set EmailWording = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("EmailWording")

    row_number = 1

    Do
       DoEvents

       row_number = row_number + 1

       mail_body_message = EmailWording.Range("E4")
       Email_Subject = EmailWording.Range("D4")
       Call SendHTMLEmail("miqi180@miqi.com", Email_Subject, mail_body_message) ' test email address inserted (not my real one)

    Loop Until row_number = 2

End Sub
```

**Edit**

Fixed the loop, thanks to `Zac`:

```
Sub SendHoldingEmail()

    Dim EmailWording As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim row_number As Long
    Dim Email_Subject As String, full_name As String, mail_body_message As String

    Set EmailWording = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("EmailWording")

    ' starting row number
    row_number = 4

    Do
       DoEvents

       mail_body_message = EmailWording.Cells(row_number, 5) 
       Email_Subject = EmailWording.Cells(row_number, 4)
       Call SendHTMLEmail("miqi180@miqi.com", Email_Subject, mail_body_message) ' test email address inserted (not my real one)

       row_number = row_number + 1

    Loop Until row_number = 6 ' change as required

End Sub
```

Comment: as codeguy pointed out, I don't think `row_number` loop has any relevance here. All it will do is produce the same email twice. If the `Row` and/or `Column` had to be incremented, I would use a `FOR` loop instead

Comment: True, will fix it in a moment.

Comment: Thank you so much. This has seemed to fix it. The error was showing with the way I had called the range on the EmailWordings sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just use "EmailWording" as if it was an object constructed within VBA. If you just add the `Option Explicit` on top of all of your code and then try to compile the project, you'll see that it says "*Compile Error: Variable not defined*". 
You have to obtain the sheet like this:

```
Dim m_sheet As Excel.Worksheet
Set m_sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("EmailWording")
```

Afterwards, change your code to use `m_sheet`.

```
mail_body_message = m_sheet.Range("E4")
```

Please note that I removed your `row_number` and the loop as I did not see how this is of any importance in your code.

Furthermore I would like to give you a hint:
Try to get the Outlook-Application before creating a new one, there might already be one opened on the user's client.

```
Set olapp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If olapp Is Nothing Then
   Set olapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
End If
```

Comment: If the codename of the Worksheet is EmailWording, referencing it with `EmailWording.Range` is just fine

Comment: @gizlmo you are right, but if it's just the `Name` of the sheet (what I assumed) and not it's `CodeName`, it's not possible.